# How to test Facebook Login button in localhost?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I'am using php with Grav CMS. It ran on php-built in server.

IP:

```
127.0.0.10:80
```

/etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.10 mydomain.local
```

In facebook I've added to app domain: mydomain.local
And after clicking a button the facebook give me information back that my domain require HTTPS. I know that I can't disable "Enforce HTTPS" option since March 2018.
How can I test facebook login button locally then?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this little tool called [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) which will setup a tunnel from their servers so your local webserver will be publicly available. They will also terminate SSL at their end.

You can use it like this (assuming your webserver runs on port 80) `ngrok http 80`. You'll now see the ngrok tunnel address in your terminal, it will look something like this:

`Forwarding                    https://******.ngrok.io -> localhost:80`

Just open that URL and you'll see your local webserver's contents. You can now add that URL to Facebook and try it out.

Hope this helps you.